# I Want To get my Current Location But It can't Respond

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use Following Code and i set delegate also
but when i click Action button DidupdateLocation and DidfailError Events never call it.Please help me to find my mistake.

```
 - (IBAction)onUseCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
         if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
       }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Longitude:-%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
            NSLog(@"Latitude:-%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution currently I found

Must call `-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` first.

But even if you implement one of the above methods, it won't prompt the user unless there is an entry in the Info.plist for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Add the following lines to your Info.plist (obviously with the message you want your users to see :),

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The spirit of stack overflow is coders helping coders</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I have learned more on stack overflow than anything else</string>
```